# Add to cart issue on product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart

I am using magento 1.9 and when adding product from product view page, product gets added to cart, but no success message is shown, and mini cart also does not get updated. When I move to any other page, message displays there. and also if I view checkout page, product shows there in cart

http://boho-magic.com/rings/long-sterling-silver-925-ring-statement-401.html

Please help. I am trying but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in your ajax cart, the message will be displayed in the next page because magento get the message success from the session but he can't display it the current page from some reasons ! so try to display it again in the next page if you have also no issue. This can je come from different things :

1. Check your ajax and theme settings from admin.
2. Check if you haven't some error in your product page `view.phtml`
3. Enable logs and see if you have some error.

Comment: @Teja bhagavan Kollepara I don't understand why you edited my answer ? the tabulation that you added doesn't add any value on my content, try to answer the questions if you want instead, editing does not help users

Comment: Hi Prince. Good morning. Actually i edited for better format only. if i disturbed you dont mind please.

Answer (score 0):

I see the quantity of items in your cart isn't updated either. Are you using varnish or any full-page cache module? If yes, try disabling it or switching to another module.

Comment: I am using Memcache and turbocache. But can not disable them for some reasons.

Comment: I have tried after disabling memcache, still not working.

Comment: I don't know this specific module (turbocache), but most "cache" modules work by caching each block of your store in a single file. The technique used for showing messages and allowing this sort of activity to happen is called "holepunching". The module caches a "hole" on the page where your cart/messages block is, and loads it dinamically according to user session. I believe your theme has different block names, which would cause the holepunching to fail.

Look for a config on your module where you can indicate "ignored" blocks, and add the names matching the blocks to the "ignore" list.